# Can a user with 2000+ change which user is awarded the answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Does a user with 2k rep have the ability to change who is awarded the answer? Or is this a privilege only the OP has the ability to do?

I ask because today I had answered a question and my answer was flagged with the green checkmark and I received +15 rep.  Upon returning to the site later on I noticed my total rep had dropped by 15.  A user with 2k rep who answered a minute later than I, was now awarded the answer.  Did the OP change their mind or did this user flag their answer as the correct one?

Comment: Switching the accepted answer (if it was about the CSS question) seems really unfair. Seeing as it was 100% identical. But, it's the OP's decision

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.  I thought it was strange but the OP is likely a throwaway account.  On the positive side I've now made my first contribution to meta. :)

Comment: Nine responses in two minutes; one wrong enough to be deleted in shame, and two deleted by owners who thought eight nearly-identical answers looked silly. What an amazing resource. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only person who can change the accepted answer is the OP (or perhaps a developer with access to the database).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the speedy reply.